# Select statement giving an aditionnal Null row

Tags: sql, performance, t-sql

So here is my T-SQL statement :

```html
SELECT 
 NEWID() as Id,
 ss.Id as SkillId,
 ss.Name,
 sc.Vote,
 sc.CandidateId,
 sc.Id As ScoreId

FROM dbo.SoftSkills ss 
LEFT JOIN dbo.Scorecards sc ON ss.Id = sc.SkillId
```

Giving me this

[image: return]

But I also would like my select to return an additional row per **SkillId** where the **CandidateId** being Null.

Is that possible ?

Thanks for help.

**EDIT** : Can't write "Hello guys" at beginning of my post so saying hi there :D

Comment: Isn't that what your query does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you just want `UNION ALL`?

```
SELECT NEWID() as Id, ss.Id as SkillId, ss.Name, sc.Vote,
       sc.CandidateId, sc.Id As ScoreId
FROM dbo.SoftSkills ss LEFT JOIN
     dbo.Scorecards sc
     ON ss.Id = sc.SkillId 
UNION ALL
SELECT NEWID() as Id, ss.Id as SkillId, ss.Name, NULL, NULL, NULL
FROM dbo.SoftSkills ss;
```

Comment: Just need to set sc.Vote to null in the second select cause it doesnt exists in ss table but yeah it looks like what I needed thank you